# Constant expression required? (Java switch statement)

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have no idea what is causing this error. My teacher and I went over it and couldn't find what was wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MailAssignment
{
public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    char p;
    char f;
    double price = 0;
    System.out.println("First class or priority?");
    char type = userinput.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("How much does the package weigh? (in ounces)");
    double weight = userinput.nextDouble();

    switch (type){
     case p:
     if (weight > 16)
        price = weight * 3.95;

        else if (weight > 32) 
            price = (1.20 * (weight / 16));
       else
            price = 3.50 * weight;


        break;


     case f: 
     if (weight < 1 )
     price = 0.34;

     else if ( weight > 1)
     price = 0.34 + (weight * 21);

     else if (weight > 13)
     price = weight * 3.95;

        else if (weight > 32) 
            price = 1.20 * (weight / 16);
        else
            price = 3.50 * weight;

            break;

        }     

    System.out.println("Your price is: " +price);
    }
}
```

It throws a "Constant expression required" error when it's compiled and it points to the case p: line, however, it also throws it for f: if I switch them so I must be doing something completely off.

Comment: You can't use variables in `case` statements, that are not declared `final`.

Comment: I was trying something similar, and it turns out that even if the variable is final, the same error will be thrown.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, a `case` expression has to be a constant (or an enum constant name) - you can't use a variable. See the [Java Language Specification section 14.11 (switch statements)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) for more details. (You hadn't even initialized the variables, so it's not clear what you expected to happen, to be honest.)

Did you mean:

```
case 'p':
    ...

case 'f':
    ...
```

? This will match your input (`type`) against the character *literals* `'p'` and `'f'`.

(As an aside, if this stumped your teacher, I have concerns about how suitable they are to be teaching Java. This is reasonably basic stuff.)

Comment: or to clarify, the case is for the VALUE of the variable, not the name of it, so the case is if the value of the variable type = 'p' do this, if it's 'f' do that

Comment: @JeffHawthorne: The value of which variable? If it's `type` you mean, then clearly its name is `type` rather than `p` for example. In short, I'm not sure your comment actually makes anything clearer...

Comment: i was trying to get away from the word constant, literal is a better word, but since "type" is a variable, and we're checking the value of type, i thought constant might confuse things

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable in your case statement, it has to be a literal char (e.g. `'p'`, `'f'`).

Answer (score 1):

In case statement
You should use a (character switch) or a (number switch) only
For example
You can use a (character switch)

```
switch (type) {
case 'p':
.......
case 'f':
......
}
```

NOT

```
switch (type) {
case p:
.......
case f:
......
}
```

Comment: Well no if you want things to be fast you should use constants to avoid magic numbers and integers to benefit from faster comparison. Java just fails to provide a reasonable method other than the enum workround for doing this.