# Constant expression required in Java switch statement

Tags: java

I have ths piece of code in Java

```
 final String workFlowKey = getProcessDefinitionKey();
        
        switch (workFlowKey) {
            case WorkflowKey.DOG_WORKFLOW.getKey():
                return "A";
                break;
            default: return null;
        }
```

but I have this compilation error: Constant expression required

Comment: `WorkflowKey.DOG_WORKFLOW.getKey()` is not a constant. Use an ENUM with your Workflow-Keys instead.

Comment: indeed, is a String

Comment: case WorkflowKey.DOG_WORKFLOW.getKey(): -> this is a method call, not a 'constant expression'

Comment: As it is not a compile time constant, you must use the shorter if statement or expression (.equals).

Comment: Please consider 'if' instead of Switch when you have to check only one condition.

Comment: @Barefooter - this is probably just the 'minimum reproducible example' which we like in this forum.

Comment: Similar: [Constant expression required? (Java switch statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091235/constant-expression-required-java-switch-statement). Search for more. You can very often get a load of good information from pasting your error message into your search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong.

Case labels must be compile-time constants. This:

```
case WorkflowKey.DOG_WORKFLOW.getKey():
```

has a method call, which is not known at compile time (according to the rules for determining what is constant).

Is WorkflowKey an enum type?  Then you should just be switching on the enumerated constants:

```
case DOG_WORKFLOW:
```

You'll need a way to get the enum value from the 'process definition' instead of the String you're getting, of course.

Comment: Here's the link to Oracle for Final Variables : [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

Comment: Not sure of the relevance of final variables; the case label is not a variable.  [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) is the JLS section on switch - it points to constant expressions and enum constants as the possibilities.  Note the JLS uses 'switch label' where I was (incorrectly) saying 'case label'.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a situation, if you could pass a method into case clause. What if the method could return different values depending on some internal factors? The same conforms to field, or variable. It can take different values during application runtime.

```
class A {
  String f(){
    if(something) return „string1”;
    else return „string2”
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A obj = new A();
    String someString = "string1";
    switch(someString){
      case obj.f(): {…} // obj.f can potentially return 2 different results. So as any method. 
      …
    }
  }
}
```

Unlike `if-else`, which checks boolean value of expression, in `switch-case` a value passed into is compared to cases inside. In compile-time Java compiler create **array of jumps** to optimize performace, so usually `switch-case` is more efficient than `if-else` for big number of alternatives. ([Good link explaining jumps, but in assembly code](http://courses.ics.hawaii.edu/ReviewICS312/morea/ControlStructures/ics312_jumpsbranches.pdf)). Hence, in order to perform that, cases' values in `switch-case` have to be determined in compile-time.